# Can't seem to create an app with a specific Rails version [Hartl's Tutorial]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I have used Rails before and have other versions installed. I'm currently trying to follow Hartl's tutorial and he asks to use a specific version of Rails and specific gems.

When I try running `rails _5.0.3_ new sample_app`
I get the following error:

> /Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/specification.rb:2278:in
>   `check_version_conflict': can't activate activesupport-5.1.1, already
>   activated activesupport-5.0.3 (Gem::LoadError)

`rails -v` returns `Rails 5.1.1`

I understand this has to do with some gem specifications but I'm unsure on how to change this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What are you using to manage your Ruby and Gem versions? E.g., rbenv, rvm?

Comment: I'm using rvm and my ruby version is:
`ruby 2.3.1p112`

Comment: And when you've installed things like Rails did you do it globally or local to your project(s)?

Comment: I believe it was global I made a directory and ran `gem install rails -v 5.0.3` then tan `rails _5.0.3_ new sample_app` and got the error above.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I tried uninstalling it with `gem uninstall activesupport --version=5.1.1` then installed the older version with `gem install activesupport -v 5.0.3` But i'm getting the same error. This so frustrating.

Comment: What happens if you uninstall all the version of activesupport, and then run the rails new command?

Comment: So I removed all the activesupport versions and got this error:
`/Users/carlosgrijalva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:308:in `to_specs': Could not find 'activesupport' (= 5.0.3) among 279 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)`

Then I installed the 5.0.3 version an managed to create the app. I hope this doesn't screw other apps If I try to user a newer version of Rails! Thanks for the help though!

Comment: If you have to work with newer versions of Rails, then it'll ask for the appropriate version of activesupport to work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your versions for activesupport don't match as requisites for those two versions, you have the one for Rails 5.1.1, but not for the version 5.0.3 of Rails.

You could try `gem uninstall activesupport`, and then install the one for starting the project in the version 5.0.3 version.

If you have to work with newer versions of Rails, then it'll ask for the appropriate version of activesupport to work with it, you can easily manage them installing and uninstalling them depending on the Rails version you're working with.